# C equivalent to #pragma in Obj-C

Tags: objective-c, c

Does C have an equivalent to the Obj c #pragma mark?

Comment: What does "Obj c #pragma mark" do? Do you want an equivalent only, or something similar (if possible) or a workaround is good enough?

Comment: `#pragma` (like other directives starting with `#` in C-based languages) is a C preprocessor directive. There are `#pragma` directives for C, C++, Objective-C, and potentially other C-based languages, depending on the particular compiler that’s being used to build the code (or whatever program is parsing the source code).

Comment: Similar is fine. The #pragma mark can be used to help organise code in implementation files.(in xcode for obj c) I want to do the same in my .c files when developing using c.

Comment: ‘Develop using C’ in which IDE/editor?

Comment: Textmate and the terminal. compiling on osx with gcc. final compilation will be on ubuntu, using gcc im sure.

Comment: I don’t use Textmate so I can’t really tell — just try it. As Ned mentioned in his answer, you need to check whether the editor you use supports a particular `#pragma`; Xcode certainly recognises `#pragma mark` for C source code. Other programs (including compilers) will blissfully ignore any `#pragma` that’s not recognised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objective-C is a superset of C. `#pragma` directives are part of the C standard, so they also exist in Objective-C also.

There are only a handful of `#pragma` directives that are actually standardised, but, any conforming compiler is supposed to ignore `#pragma` directives that it doesn't understand.
The problem though, is that “legally” the same `#pragma` directive can cause two conforming implementations to behave differently.

In any case, if you are writing C code using Xcode, then you can use `#pragma mark` for organisation; just keep in mind that it may decrease portability.

Answer (score 2):

Each compiler and IDE will support a different set of `#pragma` directives.  You'll have to investigate which are available with your toolset.  If you are using Xcode for C, it sounds like it will still work.

Answer (score -1):

I keep my C code organized by grouping related functions in different source files.

For example, string files are in "zstr.c"; big numbers are in "big.c"; ..., and I keep header files with the prototypes of the functions defined: "zstr.h", "big.h", ...

I haven't felt the need to use the #pragma mechanism (or any other beside the directory/file mechanisn of the OS) to help my organisation of code.